# Validate assemblies and namespaces in VAB config file

Tags: c#, validation, namespaces, assembly-resolution, validation-application-bl

We are using version 4.1 of the validation application block. I am relatively new to it so I was wondering if it had the ability to either abstract out the configured namespaces and assemblies or otherwise provide proper validation of their existence?

We had an issue recently where someone moved a class and didn't update the validation configuration file with the new namespace. As a result the validations were no longer being applied to the object. The application block seems to just ignore the discrepancies. Unfortunately this was not caught during the normal QA cycle. Is there any built in way to protect ourselves from this type of change in the future? What I did in the interim is load up the config xml, extract out all the assemblies and defined namespaces and validate that they all exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a set of unit tests to see if objects get validated correctly.

Another option is to build up the vab configuration dynamically in a fluent way. This will give you compile time support and refactoring safety.

There is only one problem with this: [vab has no support for this out of the box](http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/222714?ProjectName=entlib). You will have to write this yourself. Creating a VAB contrib project with such feature is on my todo list for years already, but I never had the time to do this. It isn't that hard though. Here is the code I wrote a few years back (but never got the time to finish it):

```
public interface IValidationConfigurationMemberCreator<TEntity>
{
    ValidationConfigurationBuilderRuleset<TEntity> BuilderRuleset { get; }
}

public static class ValidationConfigurationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static ValidationConfigurationBuilderProperty<TEntity, TField> ForField<TEntity, TField>(
        this IValidationConfigurationMemberCreator<TEntity> memberCreator,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TField>> fieldSelector)
    {
        string fieldName = ExtractFieldName(fieldSelector);

        return new ValidationConfigurationBuilderProperty<TEntity, TField>(memberCreator.BuilderRuleset,
            fieldName);
    }

    public static ValidationConfigurationBuilderProperty<TEntity, TProperty>
        ForProperty<TEntity, TProperty>(
        this IValidationConfigurationMemberCreator<TEntity> memberCreator,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> propertySelector)
    {
        string propertyName = ExtractPropertyName(propertySelector);

        return new ValidationConfigurationBuilderProperty<TEntity, TProperty>(memberCreator.BuilderRuleset,
            propertyName);
    }


    private static string ExtractPropertyName(LambdaExpression propertySelector)
    {
        if (propertySelector == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertySelector");
        }

        var body = propertySelector.Body as MemberExpression;

        if (body == null || body.Member.MemberType != MemberTypes.Property)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The given expression should return a property.",
                "propertySelector");
        }

        return body.Member.Name;
    }

    private static string ExtractFieldName(LambdaExpression fieldSelector)
    {
        if (fieldSelector == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("fieldSelector");
        }

        var body = fieldSelector.Body as MemberExpression;

        if (body == null || body.Member.MemberType != MemberTypes.Field)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The given expression should return a field.",
                "fieldSelector");
        }

        return body.Member.Name;
    }

    public static ValidationConfigurationBuilderMember<TEntity, TMember> AddRangeValidator<TEntity, TMember>(
       this ValidationConfigurationBuilderMember<TEntity, TMember> memberBuilder,
      RangeData<TMember> rangeData) where TMember : IComparable
    {
        memberBuilder.AddValidator(rangeData.CreateValidator());

        return memberBuilder;
    }
}

public class ValidationConfigurationBuilder : IConfigurationSource
{
    private readonly ValidationSettings settings;
    private readonly HashSet<string> alternativeRulesetNames = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.Ordinal);
    private string defaultRulesetName;

    public ValidationConfigurationBuilder()
    {
        this.settings = new ValidationSettings();
    }

    public event EventHandler<ConfigurationSourceChangedEventArgs> SourceChanged;

    public void RegisterDefaultRulesetForAllTypes(string rulesetName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rulesetName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("rulesetName");
        }

        if (this.settings.Types.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Registeringen rulesets for all types is not possible " +
             "after types are registered.");
        }

        this.defaultRulesetName = rulesetName;
    }

    public void RegisterAlternativeRulesetForAllTypes(string rulesetName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rulesetName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("rulesetName");
        }

        if (this.settings.Types.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Registeringen rulesets for all types is not possible " +
             "after types are registered.");
        }

        if (this.alternativeRulesetNames.Contains(rulesetName))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("There already is a ruleset with this name: " +
                rulesetName);
        }

        this.alternativeRulesetNames.Add(rulesetName);
    }

    public ValidationConfigurationBuilderType<T> ForType<T>()
    {
        ValidatedTypeReference typeReference;

        if (this.settings.Types.Contains(typeof(T).FullName))
        {
            typeReference = this.settings.Types.Get(typeof(T).FullName);
        }
        else
        {
            typeReference = new ValidatedTypeReference(typeof(T))
            {
                AssemblyName = typeof(T).Assembly.GetName().FullName,
            };

            if (this.defaultRulesetName != null)
            {
                typeReference.Rulesets.Add(new ValidationRulesetData(this.defaultRulesetName));
                typeReference.DefaultRuleset = this.defaultRulesetName;
            }

            foreach (var alternativeRulesetName in this.alternativeRulesetNames)
            {
                typeReference.Rulesets.Add(new ValidationRulesetData(alternativeRulesetName));
            }

            this.settings.Types.Add(typeReference);
        }

        return new ValidationConfigurationBuilderType<T>(this, typeReference);
    }

    ConfigurationSection IConfigurationSource.GetSection(string sectionName)
    {
        if (sectionName == ValidationSettings.SectionName)
        {
            return this.settings;
        }

        return null;
    }

    #region IConfigurationSource Members

    void IConfigurationSource.Add(string sectionName, ConfigurationSection configurationSection)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void IConfigurationSource.AddSectionChangeHandler(string sectionName, ConfigurationChangedEventHandler handler)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void IConfigurationSource.Remove(string sectionName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void IConfigurationSource.RemoveSectionChangeHandler(string sectionName, ConfigurationChangedEventHandler handler)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    #endregion

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
    }
}

public class ValidationConfigurationBuilderType<TEntity>
    : IValidationConfigurationMemberCreator<TEntity>
{
    internal ValidationConfigurationBuilderType(ValidationConfigurationBuilder builder,
        ValidatedTypeReference typeReference)
    {
        this.Builder = builder;
        this.TypeReference = typeReference;
    }

    ValidationConfigurationBuilderRuleset<TEntity> IValidationConfigurationMemberCreator<TEntity>.BuilderRuleset
    {
        get { return this.ForDefaultRuleset(); }
    }

    internal ValidationConfigurationBuilder Builder { get; private set; }

    internal ValidatedTypeReference TypeReference { get; private set; }

    public ValidationConfigurationBuilderRuleset<TEntity> ForDefaultRuleset()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TypeReference.DefaultRuleset))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "There hasn't been an default ruleset registered for the type {0}.", typeof(TEntity).FullName));
        }

        var defaultRuleset = this.TypeReference.Rulesets.Get(this.TypeReference.DefaultRuleset);

        if (defaultRuleset == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "The default ruleset with name {0} is missing from type {1}.",
                this.TypeReference.DefaultRuleset, typeof(TEntity).FullName));
        }

        return new ValidationConfigurationBuilderRuleset<TEntity>(this, defaultRuleset);
    }

    public ValidationConfigurationBuilderRuleset<TEntity> ForRuleset(string rulesetName)
    {
        var ruleset = this.TypeReference.Rulesets.Get(rulesetName);

        if (ruleset == null)
        {
            ruleset = new ValidationRulesetData(rulesetName);

            this.TypeReference.Rulesets.Add(ruleset);

            //throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            //    "The ruleset with name '{0}' has not been registered yet for type {1}.",
            //    rulesetName, this.TypeReference.Name));
        }

        return new ValidationConfigurationBuilderRuleset<TEntity>(this, ruleset);
    }

    internal void CreateDefaultRuleset(string rulesetName)
    {
        if (this.TypeReference.Rulesets.Get(rulesetName) != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "The ruleset with name '{0}' has already been registered yet for type {1}.",
                rulesetName, this.TypeReference.Name));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TypeReference.DefaultRuleset))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "The type {0} already has a default ruleset.", this.TypeReference.Name));
        }

        var ruleset = new ValidationRulesetData(rulesetName);

        this.TypeReference.Rulesets.Add(ruleset);
        this.TypeReference.DefaultRuleset = rulesetName;
    }

    internal void CreateAlternativeRuleset(string rulesetName)
    {
        if (this.TypeReference.Rulesets.Get(rulesetName) != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "The ruleset with name '{0}' has already been registered yet for type {1}.",
                rulesetName, this.TypeReference.Name));
        }

        var ruleset = new ValidationRulesetData(rulesetName);

        this.TypeReference.Rulesets.Add(ruleset);
    }
}

public class ValidationConfigurationBuilderRuleset<TEntity> : IValidationConfigurationMemberCreator<TEntity>
{
    internal ValidationConfigurationBuilderRuleset(
        ValidationConfigurationBuilderType<TEntity> builderType,
        ValidationRulesetData ruleset)
    {
        this.BuilderType = builderType;
        this.Ruleset = ruleset;
    }

    internal ValidationConfigurationBuilderType<TEntity> BuilderType { get; private set; }

    ValidationConfigurationBuilderRuleset<TEntity>
        IValidationConfigurationMemberCreator<TEntity>.BuilderRuleset { get { return this; } }

    internal ValidationRulesetData Ruleset { get; private set; }

    internal ValidationConfigurationBuilderRuleset<TEntity> AddValidator(ValidatorData validator)
    {
        if (validator == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("validator");
        }

        // 'Name' is the default value when the validator has not been given a name.
        if (validator.Name == "Name")
        {
            // In that case we set the name to something more specific.
            validator.Name = typeof(TEntity).Name + "_" + validator.Type.Name;
        }

        var validators = this.Ruleset.Validators;

        // When that specific name already exist, we add a number to that name to ensure uniqueness.
        if (validators.Contains(validator.Name))
        {
            validator.Name += "_" + validators.Count.ToString();
        }

        validators.Add(validator);

        return this;
    }
}

public abstract class ValidationConfigurationBuilderMember<TEntity, TMember>
    : IValidationConfigurationMemberCreator<TEntity>
{
    private readonly ValidationConfigurationBuilderRuleset<TEntity> builderRuleset;

    internal ValidationConfigurationBuilderMember(
        ValidationConfigurationBuilderRuleset<TEntity> builderRuleset, string memberName)
    {
        this.builderRuleset = builderRuleset;
        this.MemberName = memberName;
    }

    ValidationConfigurationBuilderRuleset<TEntity>
        IValidationConfigurationMemberCreator<TEntity>.BuilderRuleset { get { return this.builderRuleset; } }

    internal ValidationConfigurationBuilderRuleset<TEntity> BuilderRuleset
    {
        get { return this.builderRuleset; }
    }

    internal string MemberName { get; private set; }

    public ValidationConfigurationBuilderMember<TEntity, TMember> AddValidator(Validator validator)
    {
        if (validator == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("validator");
        }

        return AddValidator(new SingletonValidatorData<TEntity>(validator));
    }

    public ValidationConfigurationBuilderMember<TEntity, TMember> AddValidator(ValidatorData validatorData)
    {
        if (validatorData == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("validatorData");
        }

        var memberReference = this.GetOrCreateMemberReference();

        // 'Name' is the default value when the validator has not been given a name.
        if (validatorData.Name == "Name")
        {
            // In that case we set the name to something more specific.
            validatorData.Name = typeof(TEntity).Name + "_" +
                this.BuilderRuleset.Ruleset.Name + "_" + validatorData.Type.Name;
        }

        // When that specific name already exist, we add a number to that name to ensure uniqueness.
        if (memberReference.Validators.Contains(validatorData.Name))
        {
            validatorData.Name += "_" + memberReference.Validators.Count.ToString();
        }

        memberReference.Validators.Add(validatorData);

        return this;
    }

    internal abstract ValidatedMemberReference GetOrCreateMemberReference();
}

public class ValidationConfigurationBuilderProperty<TEntity, TProperty>
    : ValidationConfigurationBuilderMember<TEntity, TProperty>
{
    internal ValidationConfigurationBuilderProperty(
        ValidationConfigurationBuilderRuleset<TEntity> builderRuleset, string propertyName)
        : base(builderRuleset, propertyName)
    {
    }

    internal override ValidatedMemberReference GetOrCreateMemberReference()
    {
        var properties = this.BuilderRuleset.Ruleset.Properties;

        var propertyReference = properties.Get(this.MemberName);

        if (propertyReference == null)
        {
            propertyReference = new ValidatedPropertyReference(this.MemberName);
            properties.Add(propertyReference);
        }

        return propertyReference;
    }
}

public class ValidationConfigurationBuilderField<TEntity, TField>
    : ValidationConfigurationBuilderMember<TEntity, TField>
{
    internal ValidationConfigurationBuilderField(
        ValidationConfigurationBuilderRuleset<TEntity> builderRuleset, string fieldName)
        : base(builderRuleset, fieldName)
    {
    }

    internal override ValidatedMemberReference GetOrCreateMemberReference()
    {
        var fields = this.BuilderRuleset.Ruleset.Fields;

        var fieldReference = fields.Get(this.MemberName);

        if (fieldReference == null)
        {
            fieldReference = new ValidatedFieldReference(this.MemberName);
            fields.Add(fieldReference);
        }

        return fieldReference;
    }
}

internal class SingletonValidatorData<TEntity> : ValidatorData
{
    private readonly Validator validator;

    public SingletonValidatorData(Validator validator)
        : base(typeof(TEntity).Name + "ValidatorData", typeof(TEntity))
    {
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    protected override Validator DoCreateValidator(Type targetType)
    {
        return this.validator;
    }
}

[DebuggerDisplay("Range (LowerBound: {LowerBound}, LowerBoundType: {LowerBoundType}, UpperBound: {UpperBound}, UpperBoundType: {UpperBoundType})")]
public class RangeData<T> where T : IComparable
{
    private T lowerBound;
    private RangeBoundaryType lowerBoundType;
    private bool lowerBoundTypeSet;
    private T upperBound;
    private RangeBoundaryType upperBoundType;
    private bool upperBoundTypeSet;

    public T LowerBound
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lowerBound;
        }

        set
        {
            this.lowerBound = value;

            if (!this.lowerBoundTypeSet)
            {
                this.lowerBoundType = RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive;
            }
        }
    }

    public RangeBoundaryType LowerBoundType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lowerBoundType;
        }

        set
        {
            this.lowerBoundType = value;
            this.lowerBoundTypeSet = true;
        }
    }

    public T UpperBound
    {
        get
        {
            return this.upperBound;
        }

        set
        {
            this.upperBound = value;

            if (!this.upperBoundTypeSet)
            {
                this.upperBoundType = RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive;
            }
        }
    }

    public RangeBoundaryType UpperBoundType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.upperBoundType;
        }

        set
        {
            this.upperBoundType = value;
            this.upperBoundTypeSet = true;
        }
    }

    public bool Negated { get; set; }

    public virtual string MessageTemplate { get; set; }

    public virtual string MessageTemplateResourceName { get; set; }

    public virtual string MessageTemplateResourceTypeName { get; set; }

    public virtual string Tag { get; set; }

    internal RangeValidator CreateValidator()
    {
        return new RangeValidator(this.LowerBound, this.LowerBoundType, this.UpperBound,
            this.UpperBoundType, this.GetMessageTemplate(), this.Negated)
        {
            Tag = this.Tag,
        };
    }

    internal string GetMessageTemplate()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.MessageTemplate))
        {
            return this.MessageTemplate;
        }
        Type messageTemplateResourceType = this.GetMessageTemplateResourceType();
        if (messageTemplateResourceType != null)
        {
            return ResourceStringLoader.LoadString(messageTemplateResourceType.FullName,
                this.MessageTemplateResourceName, messageTemplateResourceType.Assembly);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private Type GetMessageTemplateResourceType()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.MessageTemplateResourceTypeName))
        {
            return Type.GetType(this.MessageTemplateResourceTypeName);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Using this code you can define your configuration fluently as follows:

```
const string DefaultRuleset = "Default";
const string AlternativeRuleset = "Alternative";

var builder = new ValidationConfigurationBuilder();

builder.RegisterDefaultRulesetForAllTypes(DefaultRuleset);

builder.ForType<Person>()
    .ForProperty(p => p.Age)
        .AddRangeValidator(new RangeData<int>()
        {
            LowerBound = 18,
            MessageTemplate = "This is an adult system",
        })
    .ForProperty(p => p.FirstName)
        .AddValidator(new NotNullValidator())
        .AddValidator(new StringLengthValidatorData()
        {
            LowerBound = 1,
            LowerBoundType = RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive,
            UpperBound = 100,
            UpperBoundType = RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive
        })
    .ForProperty(p => p.LastName)
        .AddValidator(new NotNullValidator())
    .ForProperty(p => p.Friends)
        .AddValidator(new ObjectCollectionValidator());

builder.ForType<Person>().ForRuleset(AlternativeRuleset)
    .ForProperty(p => p.FirstName)
        .AddValidator(new NotNullValidator())
        .AddValidator(new StringLengthValidatorData()
        {
            LowerBound = 1,
            LowerBoundType = RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive,
            UpperBound = 10,
            UpperBoundType = RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive
        });
```

The `ValidationConfigurationBuilder` is a `IConfigurationSource` and you can supply it to the `ValidationFactory.CreateValidator` instance. Here's an example:

```
var validator = ValidationFactory.CreateValidator<Person>(builder);

var instance = new Person();

var results = validator.Validate(instance);
```

Comment: Although I already have my solution that scans the xml and validates the namespaces and assemblies I like this implementation better. I am marking this as my accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions that comes to me is using of `AOP` programming concepts. 
In short, for example in your case, you mark the "fragile" code with some attibute and at *compile time* check if the `type`, `member function`, `property`... is in a state you intendt it ti be in.

Like a references:

[CSharpCornerArticle-2009](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/shivprasadk/aspect-oriented-programming-in-C-Sharp-net-part-i/)  (old but still good one)

[PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) (may be the best tool on the market now for AOP)

[Rolsyn](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27746) (compiler as a Service provided by MS. You can write your own small parser of `C#` or `VB.NET` code and inject it inside you CI environment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it correct, that you suggested to use AOP for validation INSTEAD OF EntLIb VAB, not as some addition to VAB?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, so I wrote a wrapper for the Enterprise Library validation which looks up all the validators in the deployment at runtime and registers them for me. I then happily deleted my XML configuration.

I've written a blog about it [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/mrsteve/archive/2011/03/25/selfconfiguringenterpriselibraryvalidation.aspx).